# Get single value without [] with json.dig Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

So i have this code to get values from a json:

```
json.dig(0,'prediction','day','0','temperature')
```

And i get this output:

```
{"value" => "5", "period"=>"03"}
```

Here it is the json file:

```
[{"origen"=>                                                  
    {"productor"=>"Agencia Estatal de Meteorología - AEMET. Gobierno de España",
     "web"=>"https://www.aemet.es",                              "enlace"=>"https://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/horas/lagran-id01030",
     "language"=>"es",                                         
     "copyright"=>"© AEMET. Autorizado el uso de la información y su reproducción citando a AEMET como autora de la misma.",
     "notaLegal"=>"https://www.aemet.es/es/nota_legal"},         
   "elaborado"=>"2022-03-30T22:43:40",                         
   "nombre"=>"Lagrán",                                         
   "provincia"=>"Araba/Álava",
   "prediccion"=>
    {"dia"=>
      [{"estadoCielo"=>
         [{"value"=>"16", "periodo"=>"20", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"},
          {"value"=>"16n", "periodo"=>"21", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"},
          {"value"=>"82n", "periodo"=>"22", "descripcion"=>"Bruma"},
          {"value"=>"16n", "periodo"=>"23", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"}],
        "precipitacion"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"20"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"Ip", "periodo"=>"23"}],
        "probPrecipitacion"=>[{"value"=>"5", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
        "probTormenta"=>[{"value"=>"5", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
        "nieve"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"20"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"23"}],
        "probNieve"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
     "temperatura"=>[{"value"=>"7", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"6", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"6", "periodo"=>"23"}],      
        "sensTermica"=>[{"value"=>"4", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"2", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"3", "periodo"=>"23"}],     
        "humedadRelativa"=>[{"value"=>"81", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"84", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"87", "periodo"=>"23"}]
        "vientoAndRachaMax"=>
         [{"direccion"=>["N"], "velocidad"=>["15"], "periodo"=>"21"},
          {"value"=>"45", "periodo"=>"21"},
          {"direccion"=>["NO"], "velocidad"=>["19"], "periodo"=>"22"},
          {"value"=>"39", "periodo"=>"22"},
          {"direccion"=>["N"], "velocidad"=>["15"], "periodo"=>"23"},
          {"value"=>"44", "periodo"=>"23"}],

        "fecha"=>"2022-03-30T00:00:00",

        "orto"=>"07:56",
        "ocaso"=>"20:34"},
```

And the wished output is just `5` that comes frome `value`

Can do it without deletinig charecters and without dirty the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding `'value'` to the `dig` arguments would give you `"5"` which can be converted to `5` via `to_i`.

Comment: if i do this i get:
``` no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) ```
is this an error of the json? or where comes from?

Comment: Well, that's because `temperatura` contains an array. Your `dig` would actually return `[{"value"=>"7", "periodo"=>"21"},  ...]`, i.e. _multiple_ hashes, not just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wanted output should get from this:

```rb
json.dig(0,'prediction','day','0','temperature').map{|e|e['value'].to_i}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: if i do this i get:
``` no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) ```
is this an error of the json? or where comes from?

Comment: @YungSifilis can you show me the result of this? `json.dig(0, 'prediction', 'day', '0', 'temperature', 'value')`I believe sometime it return the String that it's not convertable to Integer, so the error come from there.

Comment: The ouput is exactly the same... 
'dig': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the sample JSON to it? Just to clearify the structure, you can modify the values if it has any sensitive secret.

Comment: done, now u can see it!

Comment: Mate, your JSON sample it's not even valid :"< also I think the key in incorrect too. You cannot even get any result with `json.dig(0,'prediction','day','0','temperature')` when the sample data like above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243497/discussion-between-ricky-nguyen-and-yung-sifilis).